# Request client certificate for authentication

Tags: ssl, go

I would like request a certificate to the browser for authenticate members.

In nodejs we have something like http://nategood.com/nodejs-ssl-client-cert-auth-api-rest

I have read some articles about tls, but I don't really understand how use it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a short example of how to require client certificate. The trick is to manually create and configure the `http.Server` instead of using the utilitary routines.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello cert")
    })

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr: ":8090",
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
        },
    }

    server.ListenAndServeTLS("cert.pem", "cert.key")
}
```

The important part is the `tls.Config` struct which control the way the server will behave with TLS. The field [ClientAuth](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#ClientAuthType) hold the client certificate policy, in our case *Require a client certificate and verify it*. Note that other policies are available…

You should also have a look at the `ClientCAs` field of the same struct, that allow you to use a list of root CA the client must verify against.

Note: I assume that you are also using a certificate server side to encrypt the communication. The `server.ListenAndServeTLS` method still do a lot of the work for you as a side-effect. If you don't need it, you will have to dive into this [method](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go?s=50673:50741#L1712) to do it manually (and use the even-lower-level method `server.Serve`).

Comment: It's exactly what I want. And how I can access to the certificate, to see by myself the fields ?

Comment: @Druxtan you can use the openssl command line tool to analyze certificates, if that's what you mean. You can do it from Go, but you shouldn't need to if the client has a valid cert.

Comment: You can do it but it would be a pain in the ass, as this is handled internally by the standard packages.